# Windows Batch Script to Replace Environment Variables in a File

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I want to write a batch file that will take the contents of a file, and replace any environment variable references inside the file with the actual environment variable values.  Is this possible?  Basically, if a file had this:

```
%PROGRAM FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\
```

then I would want the file contents to become:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
```

after the batch script ran.  This is just one example, but I want ALL environment variables to be expanded.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If powershell is present on the system, you could do:

```
powershell -command "get-content 'input.txt' | foreach { [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($_) } | set-content -path 'output.txt'"
```

The following works with a plain batch file, though blank lines are removed from the output

```
@echo off
goto :start

:expand
echo %~1 >> output.txt
goto:eof

:start
echo. > output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (input.txt) do call:expand "%%i"
```